# React - console.log inside JSX map

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a component `Tbody` as follows (sorry for the long code) - I want to print the value of `val` in console (line #23) - note the val is inside a `map` . However, getting error - `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Td = styled.td`
  ${(props) =>
    props.rowSpan &&
    `   &&&&& {
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    `}
`;

const ListItem = styled.div`
  white-space: nowrap;
`;

const Tbody = ({ data }) => (
  <tbody>
    {data.map((row, i) => (
      <tr key={row.join() + i}>
        {row.map((val, j) => (
          console.log(val) //- gives error
          <Td rowSpan={val.rowSpan} key={val.text + j}>
            {Array.isArray(val.text)
              ? val.text.map((line, lineIndex) => (
                  <ListItem key={val.text + j + line + lineIndex}>
                    {typeof line === "object"
                      ? Object.entries(line)
                          .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`)
                          .join(", ")
                      : line}
                  </ListItem>
                ))
              : val.text}
          </Td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
);

export default Tbody;
```

**Error**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(` after the map means: everything being returned is `JSX`.

Use curly braces

```
{row.map((val,j) => {
  console.log(val);
  return (
    ... JSX
  )
}}
```

Comment: Also, it may be easier to move some of this into subcomponents.

Comment: , or ) expected

Wish I could change my vote

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to log inside JSX you can create a dummy component
which plugs where you wish to log:**

```js
const Console = props => (
  console[Object.keys(props)[0]](...Object.values(props))
  ,null // ➜ React components must return something 
)

// Some component with JSX and a logger inside
const App = () => 
  <div>
    <p>this is some component / element</p>
    <Console log='Success' />
    <p>another component / element</p>
    <Console warn='Error' />
  </div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside JSX just write {console.log(val)}
for eg:

```
array.map(item => <>{console.log(item}</>)
```

This will work